# Why might pandas resort the dataframe after joining?

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing an application where I need to pull in a single column from another dataframe. I'm getting some strange behavior. When I run the function using one dataset, everything works great. When it executes on a secondary dataset, the same code *resorts* the data based on the index. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the very same code is producing two different results.

Here's the code. I realize this isn't MCVE but I have verified this is exactly where the resorting is happening. I'm hoping someone knows *in general* why pandas might resort or not resort in various circumstances.

```
def new_curr_need(self, need):
    self.main_df.drop('Curr_need', axis=1, inplace=True)
    self.main_df = (
                self.main_df.join(self.need_df[need],
                how='left'))
    #if it resorts, happens after the join
    self.main_df.rename({need:'Curr_need'}, 
                    axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Potentially relevant info on the datasets:

- The main_df and need_df index is a string (customer name) and is essentially the same in both datasets
- The only major difference between the two datasets is that the resorting one is a good bit wider
- Elsewhere in my code is the ability for the user to sort the data in a customized way. That sorting will hold after running the function above using dataset 1 but not dataset 2.

Comment: what version of pandas you are using

Comment: I'm on version 0.24.2

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' left join operation reorders the index of the right dataframe so that it matches the index of the left dataframe.

For example, the following code produces a dataframe where the index of b is rearranged to match the index of a:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'y':[1,2,3]})
a.index = [2,0,1]
a.join(b, how='left')


    x   y
2   1   3
0   2   1
1   3   2
```

If the indices of the dataframes you join are the same, the values will remain in the same order; if the index of the right dataframe is resorted, the values will be resorted.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, I have probably understood it incorrectly, and it will be easier if you provide a minimal reproducible example of datasets that you merge, the result you obtain, and what you expect to see instead.

Comment: this is helpful, although alas, it doesn't solve the problem. I've worked around it by using `zip` to put the column I need into a `dict` and then adding it to the df. It works, but I wish I understood why the `join` function isn't acting as I expected.